# Design for non key-value data in neo4j

Tags: nosql, neo4j

I have data something like this:

```
Berlin: capital, city, germany, europe, DE3, CET
Lyon: city, france, Rhône-Alpes, europe, CET
Warsaw: capital, europe, city, poland, masovian, CET
Toulouse: city, midi-pyrénées, europe, france, CET
[...]
```

This kind of records are couple of thousands.

I've written a parser to extract data and put in neo4j like this:

```
name: Berlin
capital: true
city: true
germany: true
DE3: true
CET: true
```

This is an example node. 
If i want to find capitals I can do by something like this:

```
START obj =node:node_auto_index('capital: true') RETURN obj
```

And it's pretty works, but my questions are:

1. Can I do this better for this non order data ?
2. Maybe I can use something different than true, to quicker find. For instance 0, or 1.

Comment: START obj=node:node_auto_index(capital="true") RETURN obj but rather create category nodes for your dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many capitals are there?

You could also do a capital node and then do:

```
start capitalCategory = node(1) match capital-[:IS_A]->capitalCategory return n;
```

/peter

Comment: Same goes for your other attributes, like timezone, country, continent.  Create nodes for those and connect your cities to them.

Comment: i'd add that sometimes having supernodes (with thousands or even hundred of relations of the same type) in your graph isn't optimal. in your data this can happen for example with the type - there might be plenty of nodes connected to `city` for example. in this case, you might want to create rather a property `type='city'`on the specific nodes.